# WSS ListProperty.Title vs ListProperty.Description

Tags: data-view-web-part, list

I have an odd thing happening that I can't explain and I wondered if anyone could offer some insight. I have a site with x number of Picture Libraries, and I'm using a DVWP to display a list of all of the libraries with links to them, call it an automatic navigation list so that when you make a new one it automatically shows up on the list.

The issue I have is that the ListProperty.Title value is coming back, but the ListProperty.Description value isn't; it's always blank.

Here's the CAML and the datafields declaration I'm using:

```
<DataSources><SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="CrossList" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Webs Scope=&quot;Recursive&quot;&gt;&lt;/Webs&gt;&lt;Lists ServerTemplate=&quot;109&quot;&gt;&lt;/Lists&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;ListProperty Name=&quot;Title&quot;/&gt;&lt;ListProperty Name=&quot;Description&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart2"></SharePoint:SPDataSource></DataSources>
    <datafields>@ListId,ListId;@WebId,WebId;@ID,ID;@ListProperty.Title,ListProperty.Title;@ListProperty.Description,ListProperty.Description;</datafields>
```